# MethodSecurityExpressionOperations or GrantedAuthority better?

Tags: spring

i'm trying to reload user privileges dynamically.

i'm trying to achieve custom authorization mechanism via MethodSecurityExpressionOperations  or GrantedAuthority to secure the URL and authorize the URL based on the conditions.

i come across two flavours of Spring to handle this one is via MethodSecurityExpressionOperations and the other is via GrantedAuthority - createAuthorityList

i am not sure which one is better and which one to be used in the case of dynamic reloading of user privileges where one user privilege has been updated by another user dynamically while the user is working on...

Thanks.

Comment: Anyone has any suggestions on the above question

Comment: Any comments on this?